# Is there a library for Java Conceptual Graph Visualization?

Tags: java, graph-visualization

I need to visualize conceptual graph by using Java. and I'm wondering if there any library that i can use to make my work easier?

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

[jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)

[AbuGraph](http://abugraph.sourceforge.net/)

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org) it seems the link is not working now, try later.

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/)

Some of those libraries let you change the shape of the nodes, you can also add images instead of basic shapes. For the conceptual graph I think prefuse will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

***[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/)*** is a free Java graph library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms. JGraphT supports various types of graphs including:

- *directed and undirected graphs.*
- *graphs with weighted / unweighted / labeled or any user-defined edges.*
- *various edge multiplicity options, including: simple-graphs, multigraphs, pseudographs.*
- *unmodifiable graphs - allow modules to provide "read-only" access to internal graphs.*
- *listenable graphs - allow external listeners to track modification events.*
- *subgraphs graphs that are auto-updating subgraph views on other graphs.*
- *all compositions of above graphs.*

  *http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/*